# Not able to create records using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to create a record in Status model by taking an object from Visit model.but while passing values to create record am getting error as few filed data is required. my code is given below along with the data am passing.

`models.py`

```
class Visit(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, name="name")
   gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICE, max_length=1, name="gender")
   mobile = models.CharField(max_length=18,default="", name="mobile")
   email = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True, name="email")
   address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, name="address")
   visit_type = models.IntegerField(choices=VISIT_TYPE, name="visit_type")
   visit_purpose = models.CharField(max_length=250, name="visit_purpose")
   visitor_photo = models.FileField(upload_to="visitor/",null=True, blank=True)
   id_photo = models.FileField(upload_to="id_card/",null=True, blank=True)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
          self.date_created = timezone.now()
        super(Visit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Status(models.Model):
    visit = models.ForeignKey(Visit,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(name="description",max_length=200)
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    aproved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    visit_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    exit_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.visit.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
           self.date_created = timezone.now()
        super(Status, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class VisitSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Visit
       fields = ('name','gender','mobile','email','address','visit_type','visit_purpose','visitor_photo','id_photo')


class StatusSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    visit = VisitSerializers(required=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Status
       fields = ('visit', 'description','time','aproved','visit_complete','exit_time')

    def create(self, validated_data):
       visit_data = validated_data.pop('visit')
       visit = VisitSerializers.create(VisitSerializers(), validated_data=visit_data)
       status, created =  StatusSerializers.objects.update_or_create(visit=visit,
                                description=validated_data.pop('description'))
    return status
```

`views.py`

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def create_visitor(request):
   if request.method == 'GET':
      visitor = Visit.objects.all()
      serializer = VisitSerializers(visitor, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)
   elif request.method == 'POST':
     serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data)
     if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
         serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
         return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`Data i posted`

```
  {
    "visit":{
       "name":"Alian",
       "gender": "M",
        "mobile":"97437000",
       "visit_type":"1",
      "visit_purpose":"vvvvvvv"
   },
   "description":"this is testing!!!!!"
 }
```

`Error I got`

```
{
"name": [
    "This field is required."
],
"gender": [
    "This field is required."
],
"visit_type": [
    "This field is required."
],
"visit_purpose": [
    "This field is required."
]
```

}

I followed this [check this link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/nested-relationships-in-serializers-for-onetoone-fields-in-django-rest-framework-bdb4720d81e6) tutorial but when i used that code it worked perfectly.but when i customised its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by different methods.

Your VisitSerializers is linked with Visit Model and You VisitSerializers  supposed to expect.

```
fields = ('name','gender','mobile','email','address',
'visit_type','visit_purpose','visitor_photo','id_photo')
```

But You are sending  only Two field

`Visit` as object. It contains name, gender, mobile visit_type and visit_purposes.
`description` as Text

But Your VisitSerializers does not understand `visit` and `description` data

## 1. If you do not want to change how you are sending data and receiving data

So One way you could do is  extract necessary data from the request data.

`visit_serializer_data = request.data.get('visit')`

And You will get

`{
       "name":"Alian",
       "gender": "M",
        "mobile":"97437000",
       "visit_type":"1",
      "visit_purpose":"vvvvvvv"
   }`

Then pass visit_serializer_data

```py
     serializer = VisitSerializers(data=visit_serializer_data)
     serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
     instance = serializer.save()
        # handle you remaining logic here 
     ....
     ...
```

## 2 IF you want to change passing data.

Change to following. Since your VisitSerializer data expects them.

```py
{
       "name":"Alian",
       "gender": "M",
        "mobile":"97437000",
       "visit_type":"1",
      "visit_purpose":"vvvvvvv"
   }
```

## 3 You are passing Data VisitSerializers Change it to StatusSerializers(data=request.data)

You sending data to `VisitSerializers`. Looking at your `serializers`, `create_visitor` and `data`. You are expect to Uses `StatusSerializers` while in `POST` Method

Comment: Kindly check this tutorial what data they passed https://medium.freecodecamp.org/nested-relationships-in-serializers-for-onetoone-fields-in-django-rest-framework-bdb4720d81e6

Comment: You have not handled Nesteded Serializer Behaviours.
You are creating      serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data)
Instead Try StatusSerializers(data=request.data)

Comment: type object 'StatusSerializers' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: i got this error ` type object 'StatusSerializers' has no attribute 'objects'` data passed was `{
"visit":{
           "name":"Alian",
           "gender": "M",
            "mobile":"9743702167",
           "visit_type":"1",
          "visit_purpose":"vvvvvvv"
       },
"description":"this is testing!!!!!"
}
`

Comment: I think you need to refactor your create() method in StatusSerializer. here objects is refering to visit.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your `create_visitor` method with `VisitSerializers`. So your data that posted should be;

```
{
    "name":"Alian",
    "gender": "M",
    "mobile":"97437000",
    "visit_type":"1",
    "visit_purpose":"vvvvvvv"
}
```

or, if you want to send your data as;

```
{
    "visit":{
       "name":"Alian",
       "gender": "M",
       "mobile":"97437000",
       "visit_type":"1",
       "visit_purpose":"vvvvvvv"
    },
    "description":"this is testing!!!!!"
}
```

then change your `POST` logic like;

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def create_visitor(request):
   if request.method == 'GET':
      visitor = Visit.objects.all()
      serializer = VisitSerializers(visitor, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)
   elif request.method == 'POST':
     serializer = VisitSerializers(data=request.data.get('visit')) # <-- here get visit object
     if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
         serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
         return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but the other fields in your sended data (like `description`) will be unused. You should change your code also.

Comment: I just followed that tutorial.but they passed extra data too(UnivStudent) model.even i tried that code as demo. check Serializer create method

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza, in that article, user_data pop like `user_data = validated_data.pop('user')` and remaining `UnivStudent` data passing from `validated_data`. You created nested serializer `StatusSerializers` but even it's created, you did not use it! I prefer you to read the article once more.

Comment: passing only visit i did it before.but how to pass discription along with it to Status table with Visit object?

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: 'visit' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`  I have changed the POST logic like you have shown @uedemir

Comment: can you print your `request.data` and share here?